# In Perl, when is it passing by value/reference?

Tags: perl, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Perl foreach variable assignment modifying the values in the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059817/why-is-perl-foreach-variable-assignment-modifying-the-values-in-the-array)

It seems a sub routine parameter is passed by value, but in the following example it's passing by reference:

```
@a = (3,5,7);
foreach my $b (@a) {
    $b = 8;
}
print "@a"; # 888
```

So what's Perl's principle in designing this so that we can know well whether we are now dealing with a copy of original data or not?

Comment: Wait, is there supposed to be a subroutine here?

Comment: @Ray Toal The title is a bit misleading, but observe how assigning to `$b` *actually modifies* the array being iterated. This differs from most other languages.

Comment: @Ray Toal And a vote to close! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl treats scalars somewhat magically in that context, and sorta "pretends" that it's passing them by reference.  Sometimes it's useful, other times it's a pain in the rear.

Ah-ha, found a reference and explanation in [Programming Perl, chapter 4](http://books.google.com/books?id=xx5JBSqcQzIC&lpg=PP1&dq=Programming%20perl&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q=If%20LIST%20consists%20entirely%20of%20assignable%20values&f=false):

> If LIST consists entirely of assignable values (meaning variables, generally, not enumerated constants), you can modify each of those variables by modifying VAR inside the loop. That's because the foreach loop index variable is an implicit alias for each item in the list that you're looping over.

And thanks to ysth for the following reference from the official [perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> If any element of LIST is an lvalue, you can modify it by modifying VAR inside the loop. Conversely, if any element of LIST is NOT an lvalue, any attempt to modify that element will fail. In other words, the foreach loop index variable is an implicit alias for each item in the list that you're looping over.

Comment: yeah the first time I see the result it surprises me a lot,so I wonder if there's any general rule to follow so I can judge easily whether I'm dealing with data copy or not.

Comment: @new_perl: I finally found an explanation and reference. I updated my answer. I hope this is a sufficient answer.

Comment: Please don't link to pirated books; a better link would be http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops.  In any case, Programming Perl is wrong and the official Perl documentation is correct; LIST does not have to be entirely assignable values for any of them to be modifiable.

Comment: @ysth: Thanks for the tip, I updated my answer with your link, and changed my link to google books--hopefully that's less of a legal grey area.

Answer (score 4):

Your example isn't a subroutine, so it's not really "passing" anything.

What you have is an array (3, 5, 7), and each my $b is a reference to each element of the array.  You can think of this happening because you are iterating over the elements in the array, not iterating over copies of them.

Anytime you reference elements in an array, you are referencing THE element, not a copy.